# Horizontal barplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to reproduce a horizontal barplot (as below), using the `unvotes` data for the number of votings flagged to be "important" for each issue category. The issues are shown sorted by frequency. I tried the following but stuck at the plot how to generate by `ggplot`

[image: barhplot]

My approach so far:

```
library(dplyr)
library(unvotes)
library(ggplot2)

unique(issues$issue)
issues1 = issues %>% left_join(roll_calls)
issues1 %>%
  mutate(date2 = ymd(date)) %>%
  mutate(year = year(date2)) -> issues1
head(issues1)
```

Output of `dput`

```
> dput(head(issues))
structure(list(rcid = c(77, 9001, 9002, 9003, 9004, 9005), short_name = c("me", 
"me", "me", "me", "me", "me"), issue = c("Palestinian conflict", 
"Palestinian conflict", "Palestinian conflict", "Palestinian conflict", 
"Palestinian conflict", "Palestinian conflict")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Yep, I have edited as per request.

Comment: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(gear)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()` seems to do this. With your data, perhaps `ggplot(issues, aes(issue)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()`.

Comment: And since you mentioned sorting by frequency ... just about every [tag:ggplot2] question on SO that asks about the order of a factor variable is answered with the use of `factor(..., levels=)`. (I can't say "all questions" because I have not read all of them ... but it is a common theme among them.)

Comment: (RanjiRaj, I really like @Till's answer ... `reorder` is using `factor` under the hood, see `stats:::reorder.default` to see how :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(unvotes)
#> If you use data from the unvotes package, please cite the following:
#> 
#> Erik Voeten "Data and Analyses of Voting in the UN General Assembly" Routledge Handbook of International Organization, edited by Bob Reinalda (published May 27, 2013)

roll_calls_imp <- 
  un_roll_call_issues %>% 
  left_join(un_roll_calls) %>% 
  filter(importantvote == 1)
#> Joining, by = "rcid"

roll_calls_imp %>%
  count(issue) %>% # since we want to order the bars by frequency we count the values of `issue` ourselves instead of letting ggplot do the counting
  ggplot(aes(reorder(issue, n) , n)) + # the reorder command sorts the bars by frequency
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please make it clear that how the scale of `n` changes from 0-150 to 0-900 of yours? Is it by design or should I perform some downscaling or so? And why is there a difference in the proportion of bars?

Comment: My bad, I missed the part where you mention that you only want to include `importantvote == 1` in your question. I updated my answer accordingly, now the plots are the same.

Comment: Exactly, what I was looking for. Great help! cheers!